# How to display data when user inputs ID# in Oracle.DataAccess.Client , VB Form Application

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g, vb.net-2010

I'm new to SQL. I'm not sure if this is possible but I have two tables
called P_Movies & P_TV_Shows. P_Movies has a column called MOVIEID & P_TV_SHOWS has a column called TVID.

Im trying to figure out a statement where if the user inputs movieID it will select that certain movietitle and director. The same goes for TVID it will display that certian tvTitle and TVDirector.

Here is the code I have:

```
         'Reference Orcale'
         Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client

          Public Class frmSearch

        'Get a Connection , string into a variable'

       Dim oradb As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=" _
        + "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=------)(PORT=---))" _
        + "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orclcitp)));" _
        + "User Id=----;Password=---;"

       'Create an Oracle connection
       Dim conn As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(oradb)



      Private Sub BtnMainMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
      Handles BtnMainMenu.Click

     'Show Main Menu Form'
      frmMainMenu.Show()

      'Hide Search Form'
       Me.Hide()

       End Sub

      Private Sub BtnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
       BtnClear.Click

      'Set Focus and selects MovieID textbox'

       txtMovieID.Focus()
       txtMovieID.Select()


      'Clear textbox and label'

       txtMovieID.Clear()
       txtTVID.Clear()

       lblTitleDisplay.Text = ""
       lblDirectorDisplay.Text = ""

    End Sub

     Private Sub BtnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles
      BtnSearch.Click

    'Create Variables for the data that will be retrieved from the database'

    Dim strTitle As String = ""
    Dim strDirector As String = ""


    conn.Open() ' Open Orcale Connection'

    'Select All Varaibles From database string'


       Dim sql1 As String = "SELECT  MOVIETITLE, MOVIEDIRECTOR FROM P_MOVIES
     WHERE MOVIEID = '" & txtMovieID.Text & " ' SELECT TVTITLE,TVDIRECTOR 
     FROM P_TV_SHOWS WHERE TVID= '" & txtTVID.Text & "'"

        'Create orcale command'
        Dim cmd1 As New OracleCommand(sql1, conn)

        'Eqaual command to the user selection'
        cmd1.CommandText = sql1
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    'Create Oracle data reader which be stored in the variables created'
    Dim dr As Odbc.OdbcDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader()


    While dr.Read()
        If Not dr.GetValue(0) Is DBNull.Value Then _
            strTitle = dr.GetString(0)
        strDirector = dr.GetString(1)
    End While

    'Assign Variables to the data labels which will display them'
    lblTitle.Text = strTitle
    lblDirector.Text = strDirector

    'Close Orcale Connection'
    conn.Close()



    'Set Focus to movieid textbox'
    txtMovieID.Focus()



     End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: Your SQL syntax is not correct. Use a `UNION ALL` to get both results: `Select ... From P_MOVIES Where ... Union All Select ... From P_TV_SHOWS Where ...`. Additionally use parameters instead of concatenating the MovieID, TvId due to SQL injection concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on SQL injection, specifically for vb.net. You should add parameters. The variable in the where clause must be prefixed with a : in oracle data access client.

```
Dim sql1 as string = "Select column1, column2 from table1 where somevalue = :userinput"

cmd.Parameters.Add("userinput", textboxName.Text)
```

[Securing at .NET application on Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dotnet/cook-masteringdotnet-090821.html)

Warning: I do not know much vb.net, so forgive me, but I do use oracle access with c#...The ideas should be the same.